# Line 9: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions

Tags: reactjs

I can not figure out the error i'm getting.

Line 9:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import { compose } from 'redux'

function DrinkDetails(props) {
    const { drink } = props;
    if (drink) {
        <div className="container section drink-details">
            <div className="card z-depth-0">
                <div className="card-content">
                    <span className="card-title">{ drink.title }</span>
                    <p>{ drink.content }</p>
                </div>
                <div className="card-action grey lighten-4 grey-text">
                    <div>Posted by {drink.authorFirstName} {drink.authorLastName}</div>
                    <div>30th of August, 3am</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    } else {
        return (
            <div className="container center">
                <p> Loading Drink...</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: You forgot to return the <div> on line 9.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `return` after `if(drink)` to return your JSX.

```
if (drink) {
  return (
    <div className="container section drink-details">
      <div className="card z-depth-0">
        <div className="card-content">
          <span className="card-title">{ drink.title }</span>
          <p>{ drink.content }</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="card-action grey lighten-4 grey-text">
          <div>Posted by {drink.authorFirstName} {drink.authorLastName}</div>
          <div>30th of August, 3am</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: thank you. something so simple. i was reading it over and over and still didn't catch it.

Comment: No problem, happens to all of us... all the time

Comment: Indeed it does, sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes