# Button not redirecting to new page in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Earlier I faced with a syntax error in `GpDialog.js`, which was solved using a fix from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423166/line-9-expected-an-assignment-or-function-call-and-instead-saw-an-expression-no). However, even when the code compiles, the button doesn't work as expected, even though the `console.log` value is true, meaning that there should not be an exception thrown. Does anyone know a fix to make the redirection work as expected? Here's some of the relevant code, feel free to ask for more or a clarification.

**GpDialog.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import {
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  DialogContentText,
  DialogTitle
} from "@material-ui/core";

export class GpDialog extends Component {
  state = {
    open: false
  };
  handleToggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { onClose, selectedGP, ...other } = this.props;
    const { open } = this.state;
    const { clinic } = this.props;
    const handleToggle = () => {
      this.setState({
        open: !this.state.open
      });
    };

    function handleClose() {
      onClose(selectedGP);
    }

    function handleListItemClick(clinic, name) {
      onClose(clinic, name);
      handleToggle();
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Button variant="outlined" fullWidth="true" onClick={this.handleToggle}>
          {clinic.properties.HCI_NAME}
        </Button>
        <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleToggle}>
          <DialogContent>
            Clinic Name: {clinic.properties.HCI_NAME} <hr /> Address:{" "}
            {clinic.properties.BLK_HSE_NO} {clinic.properties.STREET_NAME} #
            {clinic.properties.FLOOR_NO}-{clinic.properties.UNIT_NO}{" "}
            {clinic.properties.BUILDING_NAME} Singapore{" "}
            {clinic.properties.PostalCode}
            <hr /> Telephone: {clinic.properties.Tel} <hr />
            Applicable subsidies:{" "}
            {clinic.properties.CLINIC_PROGRAMME_CODE.join(", ")}
            <hr />
            Distance:
            {parseFloat(clinic.distance).toFixed(2)}km away
            <hr />
            <Grid style={{ flexGrow: 1 }} direction="row">
              <Grid container justify="space-between">
                <Grid item>
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    onClick={() =>
                      handleListItemClick(clinic, clinic.properties.HCI_NAME)
                    }
                  >
                    <span style={{ color: "white" }}>Add to comparison</span>
                  </Button>
                </Grid>

                <Grid item>
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "#ff7c01" }}
                    onClick={this.handleCompare}
                  >
                    <Link
                      to={{
                        pathname: "/ConfirmClinicChoice",
                        state: {
                          choice: clinic,
                          formData: this.props.formData
                        }
                      }}
                    >
                      <span style={{ color: "white" }}>Select</span>
                    </Link>
                  </Button>
                </Grid>

                <Grid item>
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "#ff7c01" }}
                    // cannot really break out of the scope, link must be binded with a button
                    onClick={() => {
                      const files = ["67690636.jpeg"];
                      console.log(
                        files.includes(`${clinic.properties.Tel}.jpeg`)
                      );

                      if (!files.includes(`${clinic.properties.Tel}.jpeg`)) {
                        alert(
                          "No pictorial information based on current dataset"
                        );
                        return;
                      }

                      return (
                        <Link
                          to={{
                            pathname: "/PcnImagePage",
                            state: {
                              choice: clinic
                            }
                          }}
                        ></Link>
                      );
                    }}
                  >
                    <span style={{ color: "white" }}>More info</span>
                  </Button>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GpDialog;
```

**PcnImagePage.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PCRoute from "../images/DischargeRoutes/PolyclinicRoute.png";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import ArrowBack from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowBackIos";
import { Typography, Button, Card } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3, 3)
  }
}));
export const PcnImagePage = props => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  function goBack() {
    props.history.goBack();
  }

  const { choice } = props.location.state;
  const result = (
    <Paper
      square="false"
      className={classes.root}
      style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
    >
      <div>
        <span>More information </span>
        <img src={PCRoute} alt="pc route" style={{ width: "100%" }} />
      </div>
    </Paper>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar position="static" style={{ backgroundColor: "#ff7c01" }}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            edge="start"
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="menu"
            onClick={goBack}
          >
            <ArrowBack />
            <Typography variant="subtitle1">Back to views</Typography>
          </IconButton>{" "}
          <Typography variant="h5" align="center" style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            More information
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="subtitle1">
            <span style={{ color: "#ff7c01" }}>----------------</span>
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      {result}
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
  );
};

export default PcnImagePage;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Login from "./pages/Welcome";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Language from "./pages/Language";
import GeneralInfo from "./pages/GeneralInfo";
import Form from "./pages/PatientForm";
import FilteredResult from "./pages/FilteredResult";
import ConfirmClinicChoicePage from "./pages/ConfirmClinicChoice";
import confirmedChoicePage from "./pages/SummaryPage";
import PcnImagePage from "./pages/PcnImagePage";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
            <Route path="/Language" exact component={Language} />
            <Route path="/GeneralInfo" exact component={GeneralInfo} />
            <Route path="/Form" exact component={Form} />
            <Route path="/FilteredResult" exact component={FilteredResult} />
            <Route
              path="/ConfirmClinicChoice"
              exact
              component={ConfirmClinicChoicePage}
            />
            <Route
              path="/confirmedChoice"
              exact
              component={confirmedChoicePage}
            />
            <Route path="/PcnImagePage" exact component={PcnImagePage} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

**Update**
I have tried suggestions to use `Redirect` instead, and the only changes are the code snippet on `GpDialog.js`. This is the change, other than the inclusion of 1 more import statement.

```
             return (<Redirect
                        to={{
                          pathname: "/PcnImagePage",
                          state: {
                            choice: clinic
                          }
                        }}
                        />
                      )
                      }
                    }
                    >
                    <span style={{ color: "white" }}>More info</span>  


                  </Button>


                </Grid>



              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: For what I can see in your code your button is returning a `<Link>` component, that won't redirect the user to the path you want. You can use `<Redirect>` instead or `this.props.history.push(/path)` in  order to do a redirect. Check React Router's API:https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Comment: @Rodrigo I have tried your suggestion by modifying only `GpDialog.js`, which is also suggested by the answer, however the button still doesn't redirect me to the next page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning component in your `onClick` event handler won't work as desired. In your case I would recommend to use component's state and `Redirect` component.

To redirect to a new page set state's `redirectTo` object to desired value. It will later render `Redirect` component with `redirectTo` object passed to `to` property, which will programmatically navigate to a specified location.

**GpDialog.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import {
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  DialogContentText,
  DialogTitle
} from "@material-ui/core";

export class GpDialog extends Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
    redirectTo: null
  };
  handleToggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { onClose, selectedGP, ...other } = this.props;
    const { open } = this.state;
    const { clinic } = this.props;
    const handleToggle = () => {
      this.setState({
        open: !this.state.open
      });
    };

    function handleClose() {
      onClose(selectedGP);
    }

    function handleListItemClick(clinic, name) {
      onClose(clinic, name);
      handleToggle();
    }

    if (this.state.redirectTo) {
      return (
        <Redirect to={this.state.redirectTo} />
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Button variant="outlined" fullWidth="true" onClick={this.handleToggle}>
          {clinic.properties.HCI_NAME}
        </Button>
        <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleToggle}>
          <DialogContent>
            Clinic Name: {clinic.properties.HCI_NAME} <hr /> Address:{" "}
            {clinic.properties.BLK_HSE_NO} {clinic.properties.STREET_NAME} #
            {clinic.properties.FLOOR_NO}-{clinic.properties.UNIT_NO}{" "}
            {clinic.properties.BUILDING_NAME} Singapore{" "}
            {clinic.properties.PostalCode}
            <hr /> Telephone: {clinic.properties.Tel} <hr />
            Applicable subsidies:{" "}
            {clinic.properties.CLINIC_PROGRAMME_CODE.join(", ")}
            <hr />
            Distance:
            {parseFloat(clinic.distance).toFixed(2)}km away
            <hr />
            <Grid style={{ flexGrow: 1 }} direction="row">
              <Grid container justify="space-between">
                <Grid item>
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    onClick={() =>
                      handleListItemClick(clinic, clinic.properties.HCI_NAME)
                    }
                  >
                    <span style={{ color: "white" }}>Add to comparison</span>
                  </Button>
                </Grid>

                <Grid item>
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "#ff7c01" }}
                    onClick={this.handleCompare}
                  >
                    <Link
                      to={{
                        pathname: "/ConfirmClinicChoice",
                        state: {
                          choice: clinic,
                          formData: this.props.formData
                        }
                      }}
                    >
                      <span style={{ color: "white" }}>Select</span>
                    </Link>
                  </Button>
                </Grid>

                <Grid item>
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "#ff7c01" }}
                    // cannot really break out of the scope, link must be binded with a button
                    onClick={() => {
                      const files = ["67690636.jpeg"];
                      console.log(
                        files.includes(`${clinic.properties.Tel}.jpeg`)
                      );

                      if (!files.includes(`${clinic.properties.Tel}.jpeg`)) {
                        alert(
                          "No pictorial information based on current dataset"
                        );
                        return;
                      }

                      this.setState({
                        redirectTo: {
                          pathname: "/PcnImagePage",
                          state: {
                            choice: clinic
                          }
                        }
                      });
                    }}
                  >
                    <span style={{ color: "white" }}>More info</span>
                  </Button>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GpDialog;
```

Before edit:

<s>A `Link` component creates a link element, which still requires an user to click it before navigating to a new page. But there is also a `Redirect` component, which, when rendered, instantly navigates to a different location. Therefore in your case in `GpDialog.js` file you should use `Redirect` component instead of `Link`.</s>

Check out the official API docs: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

Comment: I tried your suggestion, however, it doesn't seem to be working, updated the post.

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth Is there any error popping up in browser's console when you click the button?

Comment: None at all, other than the `console.log` printing true, which I deliberately left there for debugging. To be fair, I think `PcnImagePage.js` might have some error as I linked to it using another page and it goes to a White screen, but I think if `Redirect` works well, it should go to the same White screen at least.

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth Okay, I realized that returning components in `onClick` event handler does nothing. I updated my answer and let me know if it works.